# Does this work cross browser?

Tags: javascript

Provided `Object.prototype` hasn't been modified, will the following snippet work in major browsers?

```
var obj = {length:0};
var push = Array.prototype.push;
push.call(obj,'1st value')
push.call(obj,'2nd value');
```

Many have responded that the above code is bad practice, but what makes code like this any better?

```
Array.prototype.slice(arguments,0)
```

Both are calling `Array.prototype`s on non `Array`s.

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: Interesting to see code like that. It's bad code but it works

Comment: Is it cross browser...

Comment: @Tomalak it's a simple question. "Does this work cross browser?"

Comment: Everything is cross-browser in some fashion. If you mean "will it work universally", probably not.

Comment: @Raynos Changed titled..

Comment: I hope *you're* bulletproof if someone else has to maintain that eventually. Edit: great, makes no sense now due to title change :p

Comment: @Raynos: at the time Tomalak posted his question, Lime hadn't yet said "is it cross browser". Look at the comment/answer timestamps before posting garbage like that.

Comment: @Raynos: It said only "Is This Javascript BullefProof?" at the time.

Comment: we've cleaned up the question. Was it really that much of a stretch to guess what people are saying. Be more tolerant of people who don't natively speak english.

Comment: @Raynos: I think it's pretty clear that "Is This Javascript BullefProof?" does not aptly describe what the OP wanted to know. That would be the case in _any_ language; let's stop wheeling out this "but I'm not a native English speaker" excuse at the first sign of failure. And please do not patronise me; I spend many hours here every day, guessing what people are saying. Usually successfully.

Comment: @Tomalak I've gotten used as translating garbage into coherent questions ;) You have a point though, I think I've made too many assumptions from jumping to his question to what it is now. And personally I interpret "is this bulletproof" as "will this work". I didn't meant to offend. Apologies.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say no, because this is an array. It works, but you are hammering a screw at this point. Simply use an array.

Comment: +1 Like the analogy...  People often extend `Array.prototype` so I was looking for an alternative that allowed me to loop through the properties/methods safely along with having array support

Comment: But by making it an object, it allows you to add properties using the `.property` syntax, unlike arrays.

Comment: @Jcubed I think you meant if it was a function.  Because adding properties to `Object.prototype` is absolutely forbidden.  Well unless I misunderstood you...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to go into the depths of implementation detail with this one; I'm just going to say that you're invoking a single `Array` function on an object that is not an `Array`.

It's like you're driving along the motorway in a box that *may* have any of: steering wheel, tyres, axle, floor, seats ... and you don't know which.

Depending upon how `Array` is implemented on any given browser, this may completely not work at all. Breaking the API in this manner is a silly idea.

So, **no**.

Comment: Exactly...I'm trying not to break the API, that's why I asked if this is cross browser.  There are lots of things that probably shouldn't work but definitely do work cross browser.  For example: `0 == '' // true
0 =='0' // true `

Comment: @Lime: I believe that those examples are guaranteed to work by the Javascript standard. Messing about with `Array`'s internals is not. You _are_ breaking the API by the act of trying this; whether the resulting code "works" on your specific browser (or any other browser) is a different matter.

Comment: Yeah and all the ECMAScript guarantees are always followed by all browsers.  (IE cough...)

Comment: I'm not really sure what your point is any more. I stand by my answer!

Comment: I totally agree that generally speaking it isn't a good idea,nor would I probably put this in code...but I've noticed `Array.prototype.slice.push(obj,0)` is often used on Objects like `arguments` for example.  Is this also bad practice?  Cause I'm kinda confused where the line is.

Comment: @Lime: Define "often". I've never seen that, and I'd not use any code that did that.

Comment: Often is slightly vague, but considering jQuery, prototype, underscore.js and cofeescript all call `slice` on arguments I would argue it is definitely used fairly often.

Comment: @Lime: jQuery calls `Array.prototype.slice` on non-`Array` objects?

Comment: yeah jquery does 'slice.call(arguments)' it several different places.

Comment: @Lime: Maybe `arguments` is an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Question 1:</kbd>

#### What's the different between Code A and Code B?

Code A:

```
var obj = {length:0};
var push = Array.prototype.push;
push.call(obj,'1st value')
push.call(obj,'2nd value');
```

Code B:

```
Array.prototype.slice(arguments,0)
```

---

<kbd>Answer:</kbd>

First off, Code B is wrong and should be the following.

Code B2:

```
function test(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);
    return args;
}
```

Unless defined, `arguments` exist within the scope of a function. Basically `arguments` is an object literal with the initial state of `{length:0}`.
When a function is called with an argument, the argument is stored in the object `arguments`  by the index corresponding to the argument position.

Example:

```
function getFirstArgument(){
    return arguments[0];
}
console.log( getFirstArgument(1,2,3) === 1 );
```

The purpose of Code B2 is to convert the `arguments` object into an array so you can get access to the array prototype functions easily.

Example:

```
// returns the arguments as an array in reverse order.
function reverseArguments(){
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reverse();
}
console.log( reverseArguments(1,2,3).join(",") === "3,2,1" );
```

So as you can see, both `obj` in Code A and `arguments` in Code B are the same object initially.
However, Code A is adding values to `obj`, while Code B2 is converting `arguments` to an array.

More information here:

[What's the use of array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145032/whats-the-use-of-array-prototype-slice-callarray-0)

[MDN Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

<kbd>Question 2:</kbd>

### Will "Code A" work in major browsers?

<kbd>Answer:</kbd>
Most likely. However, if you want to guarantee that it works, then rewrite the push fuction.

```
var push = function( obj, val ){
    if( typeof obj !== "object" ){
        return;
    }
    obj.length = obj.length || 0;
    obj[ obj.length ] = val;
    return ++obj.length;
};
```

Usage:

```
var obj = {};
console.log( push( obj, 1 ) === 1 );
console.log( push( obj, 1 ) === 2 );
console.log( JSON.stringify( obj ) === "{"0":1,"1":1,"length":2}" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with Javascript is like working with templates in C++. If it has what the function need it works. In this case length might not suffice for every browser. It is true that it is possible to use built-in functions like that but if that function tries to access a property which is not available in your object it will fail.

Now coming to your second point. AFAIK, ECMA script standard does not push any internal operation and even if it does browsers do not use them as hard rules, they take it as guidelines. So it is possible that your code will not work on every browser, but arguments object is implemented by the browser as well, to be compatible with its array architecture. Therefore using Array.prototype.slice.push(arg, 0); is relatively safer than using your custom object with built in array functions.

Comment: What makes arguments compatible, because it definitely doesn't inherit form 'array.prototype'?

Comment: It is supposed to be compatible, since it is basically an array of arguments, but as I said it is relatively safer. It is not a strongly typed language and you cannot be sure.

Answer (score -1):

It will work without crashing. The exact result will be the object with properties "0", "1" and the "length"==2. There is the scope replacement becasue of the "call" function using. However it's not very good practice to use this solution becasue of bad readability and maintainability. I suggest to do it excplicitly.